# nginx log 404 on different log file

Tags: nginx

How can i get all 404 errors from all the sites into one log? 
I only know how to do it on one domain and only when i change the default 404 page.

Here is how i did it on one domain

```
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
            root /home/awesomename;
            access_log /home/custom_logs/404.log;
            internal;
    }
```

Is there a way to do it without changing anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **if** parameter (1.7.0+) enables conditional logging. A request will not be logged if the condition evaluates to “0” or an empty string. In the following example, the requests with response codes 4xx will be logged:

```
map $status $loggable {
    ~^[4]   1;
    default 0;
}

access_log /path/to/access.log combined if=$loggable;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @nomadic but this will log only the errors right?

Comment: yes, default 0 (false)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same thing on all site configurations. You can put the `location` block into a separate configuration file and then use `include` to include it in all your virtual hosts.

Comment: i can use the same file  for every domain or i need to make a new file for every domain? and does it work without changing the error page? in the example that i used i was changing the error page on other domains i have nodejs handling the page and i dont want to change that

Comment: You can use the same file on every domain and include the file in every domain's configuration file.